# Make a dropdownlist save the new value that the user selects

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox

I have a `DropDownList` iniwhich on page load it loads up all the data into it, however when the user wants to make a change to what text is displayed they just simply click on the dropdown and select the new one. My question is How do I make it so it saves the new text value that they choose? Here is what I have now:

```
Private Sub cboCure_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboCure.SelectedIndexChanged

    cboCure.AutoPostBack = True

    Dim objXMLDoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
    Dim objNodeList As System.Xml.XmlNodeList

    Dim strXML As String = ""
    Dim url As String = ""
    MaterialStuff = New Message.Material

    Dim code As String = cboCure.SelectedItem.Text

    cboCure.Items.Clear()
    If cboCure.Items.Count < 1 Then
        strXML = Message.GetCureCodes

        objXMLDoc.LoadXml(strXML)

        objNodeList = objXMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Material_Cure")

        cboCure.Items.Add("")

        For Each childNode As System.Xml.XmlNode In objNodeList.Item(0).ChildNodes
            cboCure.Items.Add(New System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(childNode.SelectSingleNode("CureCodeLetter").InnerText,
                childNode.SelectSingleNode("CureCode").InnerText))
        Next

    End If

    cboCure.SelectedItem.Text = code

End Sub
```

I want the variable `code` to be the new text value that the user clicks but I can't seem to get it right, it keeps showing up as `""` or the value that is originally displayed when the page loads.

EDIT:

Here is my `Page_Load`

```
 If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

    ...code

 else
    cboCure_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e )

 end if
```

Comment: What does your page_load look like?  Is it calling a function to load the dropdown without checking if it is a postback?

Comment: @Dean.DePue `Page_Load` is in the edit, although I don't think its anywhere close to what I need... :/

Comment: Can you show us what your page_load looks like?

Comment: @Dean.DePue Actually I just figured it out! For some reason what you said in the first comment made something click and gave me an idea. I had to re-arrange where I had it in my `Page_Load` it wasn't being called in the correct spot. It works now! Thanks. I don't know if you want to put up a dummy answer and I'll accept it but thanks for the idea haha

Comment: Glad I could help a little!  Give me an up-vote!